# Time() library asking for unreachable format

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, google-api, integer

While doing test on google agenda i wanted to make a test to see if an event is currently happening.
My approch was to check if the current time (given by the time librairy)

```
datetime.now().time()
```

And then using the description comparing it using once more the time librairy

```
print(event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))) # Will output 2021-02-09T10:45:00+01:00
```

Then i parse this to obtain :

```
event_start = (start.split("T", 1)[1]).split("+")[0][:-3].replace(":", ",")
print(event_start) # Will output 10,45 which is the beginning of the event
```

Finally i use this function i found on stackoverflow to see if we are in event by checking is current time is between the start and the end of the event

```
def is_time_between(begin_time, end_time, check_time=None):
check_time = check_time or datetime.now().time()
if begin_time < end_time:
    return check_time >= begin_time and check_time <= end_time
else:
    return check_time >= begin_time or check_time <= end_time
```

My problem lies in the input format. To compare the time the format must me be XX:XX:XX which you can obtain using time(X,X):

```
#example
print(time(10,45)) # Will output 10:45:00
```

But when i use it on the previous event_start i obtain

```
time(event_start)
#TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

I know that you are going to tell me to convert it using int but i will loose the data after the coma 10.1 -> 10 and a float is not accepted

Finally my main question is : How using the googe api input can you determine if you are during the current event using a boolean as an output considering that the input is :

`{'dateTime': '2021-02-09T12:15:00+01:00', 'timeZone': 'Europe/Paris'}, 'end': {'dateTime': '2021-02-09T14:15:00+01:00', 'timeZone': 'Europe/Paris'}`

Comment: `event_start = (start.split("T", 1)[1]).split("+")[0][:-3].replace(":", ",")` Why are you using strings to begin with? you should only work with `datetime` objects

Comment: @DeepSpace considering my limited knowledgde i thaught i could compare them using int comparison at first. I know this is ugly but it was the most efficient way i found at first and it is working perfectly with event noc concerning minutes such as from 10 to 11

Comment: Everything works until it doesn't :) Python date, time and datetime objects compare naturally using the comparison operators (<, >, =, etc). No need to break down to individual integers

Comment: @DeepSpace what is the solution then you dont answer my question of how to get a a time zone (start of the event to end of the event using the 2021-02-09T10:45:00+01:00)

Comment: I will add the json which is my based output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of, generally `2021-02-09T10:45:00+01:00` does not mean that it lasted an hour but that you have a timezone offset of +1 hour, which is the timezone of many central european countries (CET). So maybe you want to get a different representation. Are you sure that the `+01:00` really stands for the duration?

If the `+01:00` truely is you duration, you can achieve what you want to get, by simplying doing string comparison if you got rid of the `+01:00`. So for example, you can do this:

```
import datetime 

checktime = str(datetime.datetime.now()).replace(' ', 'T')
eventtime = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date')) # Will output 2021-02-09T10:45:00+01:00

starttime = eventtime.split('+')[0]
duration = eventtime.split('+')[1].split(':')
duration = datetime.timedelta(hours=duration[0], minutes=duration[1])
starttime_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(starttime, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
endtime = str(starttime_obj + duration)

happened_between = checktime > starttime and checktime < endtime
```

Note that this is not the cleanest solution, a better way would be to use datetime objects as @DeepSpace pointed out.

#### Update

After you confirmed that it is in fact the offset, you could instead do the following:

```
import datetime
import pytz

starttime_str = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date')) # Will output 2021-02-09T10:45:00+01:00
endtime_str = event['end'].get('dateTime', event['end'].get('date')) 

checktime = pytz.utc.localize(datetime.datetime.utcnow())
starttime = datetime.datetime.strptime(starttime_str, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
endtime = datetime.datetime.strptime(endtime_str, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')

happened_between = checktime > starttime and checktime < endtime
```

Comment: Ok i think your are right i just created multiple events with different lenghts and the +1 stands for time zone therefore how do i obtain the end of the event ?

Comment: I am not familiar with the API but I would assume something like `event['end']` ? Maybe you can check the keys and attributes of the `event` object.

Comment: I updated my answer including the json start and end bit of the google api output